# Saving files from FreeCAD installed via snap

Tags: snap

I have installed FreeCAD (0.20.2) from snap on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. I can not save files in my home directory, despite FreeCAD has enabled access to /home directory:

```
$ snap connections freecad
Interface                                          Plug                                          Slot                                                                            Notes
browser-support                                    freecad:browser-support                       :browser-support                                                                -
content                                            freecad:foo-install-cups                      -                                                                               -
content[icon-themes]                               freecad:icon-themes                           gtk-common-themes:icon-themes                                                   -
content[kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20-all]  freecad:kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20  kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20:kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20-slot  -
content[sound-themes]                              freecad:sound-themes                          gtk-common-themes:sound-themes                                                  -
cups                                               freecad:cups                                  cups:cups                                                                       -
desktop                                            freecad:desktop                               :desktop                                                                        -
desktop-legacy                                     freecad:desktop-legacy                        :desktop-legacy                                                                 -
gsettings                                          freecad:gsettings                             :gsettings                                                                      -
home                                               freecad:home                                  :home                                                                           -
network                                            freecad:network                               :network                                                                        -
opengl                                             freecad:opengl                                :opengl                                                                         -
removable-media                                    freecad:removable-media                       -                                                                               -
shared-memory                                      freecad:shared-memory                         :shared-memory                                                                  -
unity7                                             freecad:unity7                                :unity7                                                                         -
wayland                                            freecad:wayland                               :wayland                                                                        -
x11                                                freecad:x11                                   :x11                                                                            -
```

I have open document in FreeCAD saved as /run/user/1000/doc/cb5d929d/aa.FCStd I choose `File/Save as` and can access /home. I select some directory and enter name `bb`. When I click Save, FreeCAD does not complain about anything. Now document properties says that file is `/run/user/1000/doc/630aade2/bb.FCStd` name has changed but there is no bb.FCStd file in selected earlier directory.

How to save files outside of /run?

EDIT: I have updated info about FreeCAD version. It is stable 0.20.2 not 0.21 as I wrote originally

Comment: OK - I have removed it, installed beta (0.21). Beta could save files. Uninstalled beta and installed stable 0.20.2 again. Now it saves files outside of /run.
Difference was - first time it used system save file dialog, now it uses own.